# How to move borderless child-window/Dialog in WPF

Tags: wpf, windows, user-interface, borderless

I have a MainWindow with a Border and a ChildWindow as Dialog without a Border. When a child window is open it's not possible to move the mainwindow or to resize it.

I want the application to behave as it is only one Window.

I have tried to use an behavior as in th following link but that is only moving my child window inside of the mainwindow.

[DragBahvior](http://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is a much easier way to enable the dragging, or moving of borderless `Window`s. Please see the [`Window.DragMove` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dragmove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for more details, but in short, you just need to add this line to your code in one of the mouse down event handlers:

```
public YourWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MouseLeftButtonDown += YourWindow_MouseLeftButtonDown;
}
```

...

```
private void YourWindow_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DragMove(); // <-- this is all you need to add
}
```

Users will then be able to click on any area of the `Window` (dependant upon what you put inside it) and drag it around the screen.

UPDATE >>>

So it seems as though there is more to your requirements than I first noticed. To achieve what you want, there are a number of things that you must do. First, you'll need to position the child `Window` in a particular place *relative to the `MainWindow.xaml Window`*. As you open it, do something like this:

```
Window window = new Window();
window.Top = this.Top;
window.Left = this.Left;
window.LocationChanged += Window_LocationChanged;
window.ShowDialog();
```

The child `Window` position could be offset by some set amount:

```
Window window = new Window();
window.Top = this.Top + someHorizontalOffsetAmount;
window.Left = this.Left + someVerticalOffsetAmount;
window.LocationChanged += Window_LocationChanged;
window.ShowDialog();
```

Then you need a handler for the `Window.LocationChanged` event (which is raised when the child `Window` is moved):

```
private void Window_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Window window = (Window)sender;
    this.Top = window.Top;
    this.Left = window.Left;
}
```

That's it! Now the two `Window`s will move together. Obviously, if you use an offset in the first example, then you'll need to use the same offset(s) in the `Window_LocationChanged` handler.

Comment: Then only my Dialog Window is moving. This is not what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your dialog is **Modal**, ie it was invoked with `ShowDialog()` and stops you using the rest of the application until it is dismissed, including moving the main window.

If this is not the behaviour you want, then you will need to make your dialog **modeless** by just calling `Show()`, or better yet, since you seem to want it to behave as one window, why not use WPF as it was intended and get rid of the dialog altogether?

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice if got use just an control-overlay on my mainwindow to display the content. Disappointingly i don't have that option :(

Comment: My Window is shown with ShowDialog but Show is not the behavior I wanted.

Comment: -1 For *not* providing an answer to the question. What's your reason for down voting my perfectly working answer? Retaliation?... that's the act of a bitter noob. Couldn't stand to lose the 2 reputation points without getting your revenge? Come on Gaz... with more than 8000 reputation, surely you're better than that. If not, that's really pathetic behaviour and really unexpected from a reputed member.

Comment: @Sheridan Calm down. My downvote was because your answer didn't answer the question even after your edit. The OP has a modal dialog which is preventing moving the app window at all.

Comment: If that is *really* why you down voted, then you'll be happy to remove it after you have actually tested my code to see that it *does* work... note the use of the `ShowDialog` method in my example... that should have been a clue to you that I *had* fulfilled the question author's requirements. Using my example, I can move both `Window`s as one just like they requested: *I want the application to behave as it is only one Window.*

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found an solution. I wrote an extension to the Windows class and it was quit complicated :)

```
namespace MultiWindowWPF
{
  using System;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Threading;
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using System.Windows.Input;
  using System.Windows.Media;
  using System.Windows.Threading;

  using Application = System.Windows.Application;

  public static class WindowExtensions
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Shows the Dialog Modal.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dialogWindow">The dialog window.</param>
    public static void ShowModal(this Window dialogWindow)
    {
      Window window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().FirstOrDefault(w => w.IsKeyboardFocusWithin) ?? Application.Current.MainWindow;
      IInputElement lastFocused = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(window);
      IInputElement lastKeyboardSelected = Keyboard.FocusedElement;
      EventHandler locationChanged = (sender, args) => ParentWndMove(dialogWindow);
      SizeChangedEventHandler sizeChanged = (sender, args) => ParentWndMove(dialogWindow);
      EventHandler stateChanged = (sender, args) => ParentWndStateChanged(dialogWindow);

      window.LocationChanged += locationChanged;
      window.SizeChanged += sizeChanged;
      window.StateChanged += stateChanged;

      EventHandler close = (sender, args) =>
      {

        if (dialogWindow.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
          dialogWindow.Close();
        }
        else
        {
          dialogWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(dialogWindow.Close);
        }

        window.LocationChanged -= locationChanged;
        window.SizeChanged -= sizeChanged;
        window.StateChanged -= stateChanged;
      };

      EventHandler closed = (sender, args) =>
      {
        Window self = sender as Window;
        Enable();
        if (self != null)
        {
          self.Owner = null;
        }
      };

      ExitEventHandler exit = (sender, args) => close(sender, args);

      DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler isEnabledChanged = null;
      isEnabledChanged = (o, eventArgs) =>
        {
          window.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
            new Action(
              () =>
                {
                  FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(window, lastFocused);
          Keyboard.Focus(lastKeyboardSelected);
        }));

        ((Window)o).IsEnabledChanged -= isEnabledChanged;
      };
      window.IsEnabledChanged += isEnabledChanged;
      dialogWindow.Closed += closed;
      Application.Current.Exit += exit;

      dialogWindow.Show();
      ParentWndMove(dialogWindow);

      while (Application.Current != null)
      {
        DoEvents();
      }
    }

    private static void DoEvents()
    {
      DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
      Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
      Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
      Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    private static void Enable()
    {
      foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().Where(window => !window.OwnedWindows.OfType<Window>().Any()))
      {
        window.IsEnabled = true;
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Exits the frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="f">The f.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static object ExitFrame(object f)
    {
      ((DispatcherFrame)f).Continue = false;
      return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parents the WND state changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dialogWindow">The dialog window.</param>
    public static void ParentWndStateChanged(Window dialogWindow)
    {
      Window owner = dialogWindow.Owner;
      if (owner.WindowState != WindowState.Maximized)
      {
        dialogWindow.WindowState = owner.WindowState;
      }
      ParentWndMove(dialogWindow);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parents the WND move.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dialogWindow">The dialog window.</param>
    public static void ParentWndMove(Window dialogWindow)
    {
      Window owner = dialogWindow.Owner;
      PresentationSource presentationsource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(dialogWindow);
      Matrix m = presentationsource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;

      double centerWidth = owner.Left + owner.ActualWidth / 2;
      double centerHeight = owner.Top + owner.ActualHeight / 2;
      if (owner.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
      {
        dialogWindow.Top = centerHeight - dialogWindow.ActualHeight / 2;
        dialogWindow.Left = centerWidth - dialogWindow.ActualWidth / 2;
      }
      if (owner.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
      {
        //there is no current main window position to use, center on working screen
        Rectangle frame = Screen.FromPoint(new System.Drawing.Point((int)(dialogWindow.Left * m.M11), (int)(dialogWindow.Top * m.M22))).Bounds;

        dialogWindow.Left = frame.X / m.M11 + (frame.Width / m.M11 - dialogWindow.ActualWidth) / 2;
        dialogWindow.Top = frame.Y / m.M22 + (frame.Height / m.M22 - dialogWindow.ActualHeight) / 2;
      }
    }
  }
}
```